# My Google Maps stopped working but I didn't change anything

Tags: java, android

I am making a mobile app for our thesis and I added Google maps. It's working already, then the next day when I plan to add something my map doesn't load without me changing anything at all.

This is the original:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTsD1.jpg)

And this is it now:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VtIb.jpg)

I am using Android Studio.

Comment: Check if there is any issue about your maps api key

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my bad I did not know that the API key that I got from the google cloud disappeared so I just got a new API key and replaced it in my app and it worked again.